# Gazebo effort_controller torque telemetry?

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tried asking this on the gazebo answer forum, but there seems to be way less traffic there.

I am using an effort_controller/velocity_controller, so I input a velocity and get an effort output to a wheel. This is all a black box to me and I have no idea how this works. I'd like to visualize the effort that's being generated.

Is this possible? I tried putting a torque sensor on the wheel joint and it wouldnt read anything.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342321/gazebo-effort_controller-torque-telemetry?/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, all `ros_control` controllers periodically publish their internal state to a private `state` topic.

The code which does that for `effort_controllers/JointVelocityController` is [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/b480d5f06568b31b8c68a54de8042e1d63d01534/effort_controllers/src/joint_velocity_controller.cpp#L146-L165).

Subscribing to that topic should get you messages of type [`control_msgs::JointControllerState`](http://docs.ros.org/api/control_msgs/html/msg/JointControllerState.html), which includes the `command` field which seems to be what you are after:

```
# Current output of the controller.
float64 command
```

See #q323036 for a related question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-22**:
Note: this gets you access to the internal state of the controller. What happens to the command after it is written to the `JointCommandHandle` is something else (ie: what Gazebo does with it).